# After upgrading to Exchange 2016 I can no longer send authenticated SMTP Email from ASP.net Application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, authentication, exchange-server

I am hosting (Local Servers) a variety of applications that send email, all of which have worked well until a recent upgrade to Exchange 2016.

Since the upgrade all my sent mail is going through as anonymous and several restricted users can't receive mail.

My biggest obstacle in troubleshooting this is that I manage the applications but have no access to the mail server, setting etc.

I have cooperation from our corporate IT department but have reached no resolution. I will show my code below for sending mail (pretty standard).

My real question is how can I determine if 2016 has requirements that I am not meeting, or if the server isn't set-up properly to receive mail from my server/application.

I am trying to work with the gentlemen in IT that manages the server to find settings that may be causing this, but my lack of knowledge of Exchange is holding my back. Also he is looking at my application as the problem, so we are both working out of our area of expertise.

Any advice or direction to look in would be highly appreciated.
Brandon Wood

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("ServerIP", 25)
    Dim EmailAdress As String = "MailToAddress"
    mail.To.Add(EmailAdress)
    mail.From = New MailAddress("MailFrom@MyPlace.com")
    mail.Subject = "Ugg, Why Doesn't This Work!"
    mail.IsBodyHtml = True
    mail.Body = "<p>Text Here</p>"
    smtp.EnableSsl = False
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
    Dim net As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password")
    smtp.Credentials = net
    Try
        smtp.Send(mail)
    Catch ex As Exception
        IO.File.AppendAllText("/WO_Error_Logs/Log.txt", String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", Environment.NewLine, Date.Now(), Environment.NewLine, ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, "Task Manager (EmailNoScheduleUpdate)"))
    End Try
```

Comment: Have you tried [Use Telnet to test SMTP communication on Exchange servers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123686(v=exchg.160).aspx)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, no I haven't but it looks like a good place to start. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I just realized that this was never answered. Turns out port 25 relays mail as anonymous and ignores credentials in my case. I switched to port 587 and things are working well.